# How can I get only the numpy value stored in a class instance variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example,

```
class someClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = np.array([3])
        b = self.a
        self.a += 2
```

Then both `a` and `b` are 5. But what I want is that `b` remains 3. So I want to assign to `b` only the value stored in the instance variable `a`. Is there any way that I can achieve it?

Comment: "Then both a and b are 5" no they aren't. `b` remains `3`. Indeed, `b` doesn't exist outside of `__init__` so not sure what you are expecting gere

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Actually, the real code that i am dealing with is quite different. It involves numpy arrary. And in my code, an instance variable works as a pointer... and this troubles me as I cannot find at which point it transforms to a pointer. If you don't mind, may I update my question? I am sorry for your inconvenience.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I've updated the problem.

Comment: Don't use a mutator method, assignment always works the same way in Python, things don't magically turn into pointers. Read the following: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html